# Creating a TinyMCE inline editor AND making it visible from a button

Tags: tinymce-4

I'd like to use TinyMCE 4.1.7 in inline mode.  When the user right-clicks a DIV and selects Edit, indicating they want to edit the DIV, I execute

```
var id= g.currentElement$.attr('id');
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "div#"+id,
                inline:true,
            });
```

This adds a TinyMCE editor (I know because I catch an AddEditor event) but it doesn't seem to append the editor elements to the DOM (I can't see them in Chrome DevTools Elements tab). For the editor to appear I have to click inside the DIV.

I want to change this behavior so that when the user right-clicks the DIV and selects Edit, my handler will also trigger whatever is triggered now by clicking in the DIV.  So after I've launched the editor, as above, I need to call some other method that will append the editor to the DOM and make it visible, so clicking Edit in the context menu is all I need to bring up the TinyMCE editor.

Could someone tell me what I need to do to accomplish this?

(The reason I can't just click the DIV to bring up the editor is that a click already means something else. A single click selects the DIV, where it can be deleted, duplicated, nudged, etc. A drag on the DIV moves it.  And a drag on a DIV corner resizes the DIV. A right-click with an Edit option is all I have left.)

Thanks for your help.

Steve

Answer (score 6):

I got this working as follows.
I first run the tinymce init:

```
var id= g.currentElement$.attr('id');
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div#"+id,
    inline:true,
});
```

That creates an editor for the element but doesn't render or show it. Rendering and showing the editor normally requires a mousedown on the element.

After stepping through a lot of tinymce code I realized that firing a focusin event on the editor instance is what gets the editor rendered and displayed.  So I created a callback for AddEditor. The AddEditor event comes in early in the editor create process, though, and I didn't want to fire focusin until the editor was complete, so at the AddEditor event I get the editor instance and create a callback for "NodeChange," which happens at the end of the editor create.

When NodeCreate comes in I fire a "focusin" on the editor and that renders and displays the editor, as I wanted. A single click, now, runs tinymce init and leaves an inline editor displayed and ready on top of the element.

The total code is:

```
tinymce.on('AddEditor', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {  // now that we know the editor set a callback at "NodeChange."
        e.target.fire("focusin");       // NodeChange is at the end of editor create. Fire focusin to render and show it
    });
});
```

If anyone sees anything wrong with this I'd be very grateful for any comments.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Steve, your solution works, it was helpful for me, you can mark your answer as the best. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "div#"+id,
    inline:true,
    setup: function (ed) {
       ed.on('init', function(e) {                        
          e.target.fire("focusin");
       });
    }
});
```

This will do the trick for the initiating editor instance. Better then globally firing for every single NodeChange event for every single editor instance on the page. (Assuming there multiple editors but also works with single editor.)

**BUT WAIT...**

There is a better practice using JS Promises. tinymce.init returns a Promise Object.

```
let tinyMcePromise= tinymce.init({
    selector: "div#"+id,
    inline:true
});

tinyMcePromise.then(function(editors){
    editors[0].focus();
});
```

Official documentation: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#init

Beware: Some older versions of tinyMce have a bug about init Promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please first add jquery and tinymce library..**   

 <script src="latestjquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea>here firstly onlciki will show menu and when edit will be selcted then it will be converted into ediotr</textarea>
      </form>
    <ul class='custom-menu'>
      <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
      <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
      <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    //Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
    $("textarea").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();

        // Show contextmenu
        $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

        // In the right position (the mouse)
        css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
        });
    });


    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $("textarea").bind("mousedown", function (e) {

        // If the clicked element is not the menu
        if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

            // Hide it
            $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
        }
    });


    // If the menu element is clicked
    $(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
          tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea"
         });
        // This is the triggered action name
        switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

            // A case for each action. Your actions here
            case "first": alert("first"); break;
            case "second": alert("second"); break;
            case "editor": alert("editor will appear"); 

            break;
        }

        // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
      });
    </script>   
    <style>
    .custom-menu {
        display: none;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background: #FFF;
        color: #333;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .custom-menu li {
        padding: 8px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .custom-menu li:hover {
        background-color: #DEF;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see how this solves my problem.